# How to pass in a list of arguments to a custom Django REST Framework API?

Tags: arrays, django, list, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a Django application that exposes RESTful APIs built with the [**Django-Rest-Framework**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

My APIs are all custom APIs. IE, I don't use `ModelSerializers`.
Here is what my serializer looks like:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    my_email = serializers.EmailField()
    my_string = serializers.CharField()
    my_integer = serializers.IntegerField()
```

But I would like to modify this serializer and the (associated view) such that there is a new parameter that takes a list of integers. How do I implement lists/arrays/collections through Django-Rest-Framework? I have been unable to find any answers in the documentation or by Googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the django rest framework documentation:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields

on the `Third party packages` section, DRF Compound Fields does the job, you can find more info here:  https://github.com/estebistec/drf-compound-fields

but in this case would be:

```
from drf_compound_fields.fields import ListField

class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...
    my_list_of_integers = ListField(serializers.IntegerField())
```

regards